# trying to link image to specific model id in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I'm having a routing issue with an image.  In my app I have images of items on the home page.  I would like them to link to their image page.

Here is what my items controller looks like:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

This is what I have in my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :items
end
```

And this is what I have in the item partial:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag(item.image.url(:thumb)), item_path(:id)) %>
```

What I expected after reading the rails routing guide was that this would link to the item page for that image.  Here is their example:

```
photo_path(:id) returns /photos/:id (for instance, photo_path(10) returns /photos/10)
```

I should also add that this is in my home page controller:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  @items = Item.where.not(category_id: 1)
  end
```

However, that is not working.  I've tried several different things, but all produce errors.  Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to do what you want is this:

```
<%= link_to item_path(item) do %>
  <%= image_tag(item.image.url(:thumb)) %>
<% end %>
```

You can just pass the instance of the item to `item_path` and also if you have complicated html for a link, it is usual to put it in a block for the link as shown here (with `link_to something do`).